# Never know which profile(s) combination to sign with

Tags: ios, xcode

I never know which profiles I am supposed to be signing a build and signing a release for ad-hoc distribution with.

I've tried signing the build with the ad-hoc distribution profile and then the package with the push profile but that didn't work, so just tried many combinations until I hit one that worked.

Yesterday after months of hassle-free operation regarding signing I had to re-install XCode after it kept crashing and then I could no longer sign for development on my own phone nor for ad-hoc distribution onto other's phones.

I tried dozens of combinations of different profiles until eventually I got an ad-hoc release that I could install on somebody else's phone, but then XCode crashed again and I've lost what that combination was, making me want to cry, and I don't want to go through that process of trying all possible combinations again.

Within XCode in the Code Signing Identity section I have the following choices:
a) Apple Push Profile
b) iOS Team Provisioning Profile
c) NNN Development Profile, where NNN is the name of the project/product being developed
d) iPhone Distribution Company Name which is described as an identity without provisioning profiles.
e) ad hoc distribtion

Which of these 5 above should I be using to sign a build to run on my own device using XCode? Do I need to change it to ad-hoc distribtion when building to send a package to others to install via itunes?

Secondly, once I've built an archive and want to create an ad-hoc deployment to send it to testers for them to install via iTunes, there is the additional step of signing the built package, for this I am offered the following choices:
1) Apple Push Profile
2) NNN Development Profile
3) iOS Team provisioning Profile

Which of these 3 should be used to sign the ad-hoc deployment.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This might be better as several separate questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 4 provisioning profiles for my apps.

One is the iOS Team provisioning profile supplied by Xcode

The other 3 I've generated via the Apple iOS Provisioning Portal.

- 1 development profile that is general for my company:BlahBlah.com.myCompany.*
- 1 adhoc distribution profile that is also general for my company:differentBlaBlah.com.myCompany.*
- 1 Distirubution profile that is product-specific: BlahBlah.com.myCompany.NNN

When I test on my machine, I use the Xcode-generated one. When I run it on my devices, I use the dev. profile. When I build for distribution to testers, I use the adhoc. When I upload to iTunes, the 3rd.

No entitlements anywhere.

HTH!

Janene

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused by something - if I go to Apple's provisioning portal and click on the distribution tab on the left hand side then that is where my ad-hoc profile is. Therefore the ad-hoc profile is a distribution profile.Are you therefore saying you have two distribution profiles listed in that section? And you use the ad-hoc to sign when building the archive, then use the other to sign the .ipa that is created out of the archive?

Comment: Yes I have 2 there. Click in New Profile and you get the choice of creating AdHoc or AppStore. When building for the AppStore use the AppStore Distribution profile, otherwise use ad hoc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not building for the app store, I'm building for in-house distribution of builds which testers install via iTunes, and my question is which combination of profiles to use for that situation. Have I missed something?